# Why does Qt have problems handling small QGraphicsItems

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, 2d

When I define several QGraphicsitems with small dimensions e.g. transforming metric lines directly into QGraphicLineItems with the same length (e.g few Meters) the whole redering system becomes very slow and even is prone to crashes. On the other hand, when the items are "bigger" (length > 100) no problems arise.

To give a more concrete example: I use the following code to transform QGraphicItems into a pixmap.

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem* transformToPixmapItem(std::vector<QGraphicsItem>& items,int maxRes){
    QRectF boundingRect;
    boostForeach(QGraphicsItem* pItem,items) {
      boundingRect = boundingRect.united(pItem->boundingRect());
    }
    QSize size(boundingRect.size().toSize());
    double const scale = std::min(16.0,double(maxRes)/boundingRect.size().width());
    QPixmap pixmap(size*scale);
    pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
    QPainter p(&pixmap);
    //p.setCompositionMode( QPainter::CompositionMode_Source );
    p.translate(-boundingRect.topLeft()*scale);
    p.scale(scale,scale);
    QStyleOptionGraphicsItem opt;
    boostForeach(QGraphicsItem* item,items) {
      item->paint(&p, &opt, 0);
    }
    p.end();
    deleteVector(items);
    QGraphicsPixmapItem* item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap);
    item->setScale(1.0/scale);
    item->setOffset(boundingRect.topLeft()*scale);
    qDebug() << "Pixmap done. 1/Scale " << 1.0/scale;
    return item;
}
```

On "bigger" items this works fine on small items it crashes, the condition seems to be 1/scale. If this value used to downsize the resulting pixmap item gets too small the function completes but the rendering of the resulting item crashes. 
Besides this, as already stated the rendering of objects whose physical size has been augmented e.g. by factor 100 seems to be much faster than small objects.
Is there some general guide line on recommended Graphic dimensions and where does this effect come from ?

Comment: Where does it crash and what's the stack trace like?

Comment: Are you able to profile and determine what the slow part is? Seems like a heavy operation. How often is this called? Just one-off on demand?

Comment: @jdi I have not profiles it up to now since the main load is caused inside the qt framework "after" the termination of the shown function. I first need to the valgrind ramp to the point where the image is actually drawn and that takes quite q while. Any idea how to profile calls into a closed framework faster ?